# Setting the memory location of a statically allocated object

Tags: c, memory-management, assembly

I have the following code:

```
struct str {
    int a;
    int b;
};

extern struct str c;
```

In assembly (with GNU as), I can set the memory location of `c` like so:

```
.global c
.set c, 0x12345678
```

Is there a way to portably do this in C? This code is for a microcontroller, so I wouldn't consider it a "bad practice".

Comment: Since C doesn't know anything about linking or addresses, it's hard to imagine a "portable C standard solution". But your linker documentation should be able to give you some ideas. Perhaps you can write your own custom linker script for `ld`, for example.

Comment: A *locator* is a standard tool in embedded coding tool chains.

Comment: what do you mean when you say portable?  obviously the meaning of that address would be specific to that platform, so ... portable in what sense?

Comment: Hans: Could you please elaborate? I'm using GCC + Binutils for AVR.
thang: Portable in that sense that I'm writing standard C (or at least C as understood by GCC without using platform-specific attributes).

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You can write code that should *compile* with essentially any compiler. What happens after that will depend though.

```
 struct str *c = (struct str *)0x12345678;
```

As I said, this much should compile with just about any compiler (though it could be rejected if the number you use is one the compiler doesn't think can be turned into an address). When you attempt to dereference the pointer will depend on how the compiler translates that to an actual address (varies, but intended to be what somebody who knows addressing for the machine will expect) and whether the address it generates is one to which you actually have access (and if so, exactly what access you have).

Comment: wait a minute.. what kind of number does the compiler not think it can turn into an address? (besides bigger than the address space, but that's just like an int overflow)  i used this method quite often on old machines to target specific regions of the address space that is mapped to some device.  i don't see why this is an issue?  of course, if the address is unmapped or you don't have access to it, then you'll just get an exception...  so nowadays things are more complicated because of the selectors.  i think that doing things this way (on x86) means you are pointing to memory @ c with ds.

Comment: @thang: The short answer is: it depends. Yes, it could overflow. You might also (e.g., on x86 protected mode) hit a segment selector to which you don't have access. The basic point is: yes, if you give what seems like it should be a valid address for the target machine, chances are pretty good it will be -- but obviously the standard can't guarantee anything, and the code almost certainly won't port to anything else (without rewriting).

Comment: I could quite easily do this instead, but I was wondering if one could do otherwise. One use could be putting multiple variables at the same memory location, creating a kind of "alias".

Comment: @user381521 i don't think that is possible, but it seems they figured out that it may be a cool thing to do and added it to c++ :p

Comment: @user381521: You can do that by defining a union type, and using the same technique with it instead of a struct.